# Modular vimrc: how to source vundle Plugins from diffrent files

Tags: vim, plugins, modular, vundle

I want to break down my vimrc in diffrent components. I manage my vim Plugins with Vundle and I want to have one file per plugin that tells vundle to manage it and to set configuration like this:

vundle.vim:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off 
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
"Plugin in here:
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
"Plugin Options:
```

and
syntastic.vim:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
"Plugin in here:
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
"Plugin Options:
" - Python:
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['pylint', 'flake8']
let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors = 1
```

and so on.

If I now call this vimrc:

```
source vundle.vim
source syntastic.vim
```

only the last Plugin shows up in vundles Plugin list, other configurations are read though.
I guess, vundle calls the 'vundle#begin()'/'vundle#end()' part only upon call (:PluginXXX) and therefore only returns the content of the file last sourced.
How can I solve this problem?
Can I use something like

```
PLUGINS = "Plugin gmarik/vundle"
PLUGINS = $PLUGINS + "Plugin scrooloose/syntastic"
...
```

and call

```
vundle#begin()
$PLUGINS
vundle#end()
```

in my vimrc?
If so, what is the syntax for vim variables?

Answer (score 1):

`~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype off 
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

runtime! config/*.vim

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
...
```

`~/.vim/config/syntastic.vim`

```
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'

let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['pylint', 'flake8']
let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors = 1
...
```

And so on. But that's IMO a lot of work for zero benefit.

Comment: I don't think this will work - https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/119. Can use vundle#rc() but at the cost of performance.

Comment: The benefit is modularity makes plugins easier to managed, i.e., add or remove. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.nvim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'rking/ag.vim'
...
call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on

runtime! vundle/*.vim
```

Which means I get the performance of `vundle#begin()` and `vundle#end()` combined with the modularity of having settings for each plugin in their own file. This setup gave the unexpected advantage of having less plugin files to manage, i.e., the `Plugin` one-liners. Now the only plugin, .vim, files I have are the ones with additional configuration.

The disadvantage of this setup is I have to remove the plugin from two places.

The advantages are: increased performance; you still have fairly modular plugin settings, making them easier to add and remove.